# INDEX MATCH - Match Type +1 (for equal or lower) works. Match Type -1 (equal or higher) returns error

Tags: excel, indexing, match

As you see from images below (if they are posting correctly, forgive me this is my first post here after much lurking) I have an INDEX MATCH function that works correctly when using 'match type' +1 for equal or lower value but returns an error for match type -1 equal or higher value. Not really sure what other unique information is relevant but happy to add more details if necessary. I have scoured google for a fix but could not find this particular behavior. Worth mention I am matching dates, however, both columns are formatted exactly the same and, again, if it works for +1 then why would it not work for -1? Thanks in advance.

In the images you'll see I am trying to return a value on worksheet 1 from an equal or later date on worksheet 2. In the example, I am looking to return a value for 5/1/21 or later. When using +1 it successfully returns value for 4/25/21 since there is not exact 5/1/21. However, should match type -1 return the 5/2/21 date (equal or greater?). I must be missing something.

[Worksheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxQIv.png)

[Worksheet 2 using match type +1 works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV2RI.png)

[Worksheet 2 using match type -1 returns error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7BxV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Match with -1 only works if the lookup column (Date) is sorted into descending order. Then it gives the position of the last value which is greater than or equal to the value you are trying to match.

So if you were to sort your data into descending order of date like this (I'm assuming it's in Sheet3), it would work and match the next latest date:

[image]

as follows:

[image]